# Can I include npm (or similar) modules inside Couch views?

Tags: couchdb, npm

I want to run an npm module as part of my map function. I realise it's possible to include CommonJS-style modules as strings within the view document. But including a whole npm module in this way along with its dependencies is a little impractical. Is there a way to include npm modules as external files?

Comment: Not yet, but there has been discussion about adding that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, no. You would have to use the CommonJS method you are suggesting. Just be warned that you might have to compile the module and its dependencies into one body of JS to be most effective, and not all Node behaviors will be found in CouchDB since it uses a different engine.

As Dominic mentions, there has been a lot of discussion on this topic for the last year or so.